# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TopTrumpGame.ChanceCard' and 'TopTrumpGame.ChanceCard'

Tags: c#, numbers, compare

Hi Guys i'm trying to make my first GUI game compare two numbers gained from a chance card.

```
public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
mine = new ChanceCard();
MessageBox.Show("Chance Card:" + mine.ChanceCardNumber());
opponents = new ChanceCard();
MessageBox.Show("Opponents Chance Card:" + opponents.ChanceCardNumber());

if (mine > opponents)
{
MessageBox.Show("Highest number - you go first");
}
else
MessageBox.Show("Lowest number - computer goes first");
```

This is all in my button3_Click which is my ChanceCard button.
'mine' and 'opponents' are at the top of my form/main as:

```
ChanceCard mine;
ChanceCard opponents;
```

now in my ChanceCard class, I have tried to implement get & set but I don't think I have done that correctly.

```
private int chanceNumber;
private int[] chanceCards = new int[16]{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5};

public int mine
{
get {return setMine;}
set {setMine = value;}
```

I have done the same for setOpponents, yet I don't think I've done it right. I've had a mental block today so if someone could explain to me in 5 year old language what i've done wrong, it will be much appreciated as this program is frustrating me

Comment: I suppose you ignored everything that was posted in your previous question :/

Comment: No mate, i just couldn't really understand it :/ I literally need this spelled out to me haha, I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this if statement

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare reference types using `>` unless you [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the operator.

```
public static bool operator >(ChanceCard card1, ChanceCard card2){
return card1.myValueTypeVar > card2.myValueTypeVar;
}
```

Comment: Someone recommended I did it this way and it made sense up until that error popped up. i am not sure how to rectify it.

Answer (score 1):

The ChanceCard type doesn't know how to compare itself to another ChanceCard. Assuming ChanceCard had some type of value, e.g.:

```
if (mine.Value > opponents.Value)
{
   MessageBox.Show("....");
}
```

You could do it that way. Alternatively, I believe you could write a comparator, or have ChanceCard implement IComparable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

Comment: I have tried this, however it seems to only find that the computers card is always higher even when its not

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the property, not the class.

```
if (mine.mine > opponents.mine)
```

would work.

Comment: I've just tested this and it only writes down that I lose even if i get a higher number: